# Strange titanium bug, register for push notifications

Tags: javascript, ios, notifications, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

This was working fine before, but then it became erratic.

I have a base window controller which registers push notifications, all other windows in the navigation window stem from here:

```
//when base window is set up, set up push notifcations
//register push notifications

    function registerPushNotifications() {

        Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
            types : [Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE, Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT],
            success : function(e) {
                var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
                Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: " + deviceToken);
                Ti.API.info("Push notification types: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);
                Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);

                Ti.API.error("device Token is: " + e.deviceToken);

                //return device Token to store in Model.
                return e.deviceToken;
            },
            error : function(e) {
                Ti.API.info("Error during registration: " + e.error);
            },
            callback : function(e) {
                // called when a push notification is received.
                //var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                alert(e);
                var data = e.data;

                var badgeCount = Ti.UI.iPhone.getAppBadge();
                //Will return the app badges
                badgeCount = badgeCount + 1;
                //Incrementing the appbadge
                Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(badgeCount);
                //Setting new appbadge

                var message = data.message;

                /*
                if (message != '') {
                var my_alert = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title : '',
                message : message
                });
                my_alert.show();
                }
                */

                var location = data.path;
                var parts = location.split('/');
                var index = parts.length - 1;

                //get type id
                var id = parts[index];
                var type = parts[0];

                //if push notification came from background, open window if not current window
                if (e.inBackground == 1) {


                        } else {

                            //update view directly after entering app from the background.

        });

    };
```

This function registers for push notifications.

Until recently, my app started acting erratic. Whenever I receive a push notification, if I log out then log back in and fire the registerPushNotifications function again in the process. It will keep on firing older push notifications, with the e.inBackground property being set to 1. Despite not clicking on the push notification from the background.

I have tried to unregister for push notifications upon log out, like this:

```
} else if (e.row.name == '_logout') {
    Ti.API.info('Logout');
    Alloy.Globals.facebookModule.logout();
    //alert(Alloy.Globals.navGroup);
    var login = Alloy.createController('index', {}).getView();
    login.open();
    //clear base controllers
    Alloy.Globals.navGroup.close();
    Alloy.Globals.baseController.close();
    Alloy.Globals.baseController = null;
    Ti.Network.unregisterForPushNotifications();
```

But I have had no luck.

I have ALSO tried to reset push notifications by deleting the app, changing date time and clicking ok for using push notifications when the dialog comes back again. But it does not work.

So, I am not sure what to do - and why this problem is occurring. I have reverted the code back to an older version of the code. Same problem.

Any ideas why this is happening, cheers.

**UPDATE:**

The bug is very strange and frustrating indeed!

I have just isolated it further, it seems to bug up if I get push notifications in the foreground.

If I go back to the window that is responsible for registering push notifications, the foreground push notification will keep on executing, but this time thinking it came from the background.

```
function registerPushNotifications() {

    Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
        types : [Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE, Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT],
        success : function(e) {
            var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
            Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: " + deviceToken);
            Ti.API.info("Push notification types: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);
            Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);

            Ti.API.error("device Token is: " + e.deviceToken);

            //return device Token to store in Model.
            return e.deviceToken;
        },
        error : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Error during registration: " + e.error);
        },
        callback : function(e) {
            // called when a push notification is received.
            //var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            alert(e);
            var data = e.data;

            var badgeCount = Ti.UI.iPhone.getAppBadge();
            //Will return the app badges
            badgeCount = badgeCount + 1;
            //Incrementing the appbadge
            Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(badgeCount);
            //Setting new appbadge

            var message = data.message;
        }});

};

registerPushNotifications();

$.winLogin.open();
```

Really frustrating bug - quite stuck. :(

**update 2:**

```
var deviceToken = null;


if(Alloy.Globals.testFlag==0){  
Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
    // Specifies which notifications to receive
    types: [
        Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
        Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
        Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
    ],
    success: deviceTokenSuccess,
    error: deviceTokenError,
    callback: receivePush
});
// Process incoming push notifications
function receivePush(e) {
    alert('Received push: ' + e);
}
// Save the device token for subsequent API calls
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
    deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
    Alloy.Globals.testFlag = 1;
}

function deviceTokenError(e) {
    alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}

}
```

I have wrapped a global variable which is a flag around the register for push notifications event listener.

I am not getting this bug anymore.

So it seems as though that every time the window is opened (and closed), this event listener is being duplicated causing strange behaviour.

I am not sure why this is happening, when the closed window should be removed from memory, so should the event listener. Or does the event listener behave like this - once it is set in the app, it is stored in global memory?

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault, that is a bug in titanium NetworkModule.m.

There is a function 'registerForPushNotifications' in NetowrkModule.m, at the end of function,

```
// check to see upon registration if we were started with a push 
// notification and if so, go ahead and trigger our callback
id currentNotification = [[TiApp app] remoteNotification];
if (currentNotification!=nil && pushNotificationCallback!=nil)
{
    NSMutableDictionary * event = [TiUtils dictionaryWithCode:0 message:nil];
    [event setObject:currentNotification forKey:@"data"];
    [event setObject:NUMBOOL(YES) forKey:@"inBackground"];
    [self _fireEventToListener:@"remote" withObject:event listener:pushNotificationCallback thisObject:nil];
}
```

Titanium cached remoteNotification as a variable in TiApp.m, it will fire the event straightforward after pn registration.

You can either comment out this part codes, or force abandon all callback events before your push token get back.